# Sum of two random variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

In my case, I want to display the total of *heads+tails*, each time I press `toss`, so that toss in this case will be also changing dynamicaly.

The problem is that how can I add heads+tails and show their total each time I clicks on toss.

**Here is my code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var heads = 0;
        var tails = 0;

        function toss() {
            var headsField = document.getElementById("heads");
            var tailsField = document.getElementById("tails");

            if (flip()) {
                ++heads;
                headsField.value = heads;
            } else {
                ++tails;
                tailsField.value = tails;
            }
        }
        // end function toss
        function flip() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) == 1
        }
        // end function flip
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Heads</td>
                <td><input id="heads" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tails</td>
                <td><input id="tails" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input onclick="toss()" type="button" value="Toss"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the spacebar?

Comment: isn't it simple like `var total = heads+tails`?

Comment: does not work with me :s Any help ?

Comment: Works fine for me: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ks653/2/)

Comment: Remove `<!--` from the beginning of the script, or use it's ending markup too (`// -->`).

Comment: @downvoters please explain why? There is nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: In the long term your toss will result 9 out of 10 times in tail. Is that by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `heads + tails`. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ks653/4/).

**New Table Row**

```
<tr>
   <td>Total</td>
   <td>
      <input id="total" type="text">
   </td>
</tr>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var heads = 0;
var tails = 0;

function toss() {
    var headsField = document.getElementById("heads");
    var tailsField = document.getElementById("tails");
    var total = document.getElementById("total");

    if (flip()) {
        headsField.value = ++heads;
    } else {
        tailsField.value = ++tails;
    }

    total.value = (heads + tails);
} // end function toss
function flip() {
    var msg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) == 1;
    return msg;
} // end function flip
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Html Table]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/td2zK) I created a while ago. Maybe it's useful to you. It simulates flipping a coin by taking a random number and determine if it's odd ([H]ead) or even ([T]ail):

```
tmp[i] = ( (Math.floor(Math.random()*10))%2 ? 'H' : 'T' );
```

Comment: This is completely different from the original question.

Comment: Hence: *Maybe it's useful to you*